# How is 6-player Castle Panic (with wizard tower) supposed to work?

Tags: castle-panic

Has anyone played Castle Panic with 6 players?

I've tried and I think that the rules don't make sense. With more players you actually need more cards, not fewer. Sure you can trade two cards, but even if you use all your cards each turn, the amount of damage just won't equate to the amount of hit-points of the incoming monsters.

Did you house rule the number of cards? If so, how many?

Answer (score 3):

The point of reducing the number of cards is to keep the players from having too many resources at their disposal. If you have 5 players with 5 cards each, that's 25 cards for the players to work with. If you have 6 players with 4 cards each, that's 24. It's about the same number of resources in total.

Being able to trade twice is a huge advantage in resource management; I suspect the lower number of cards is actually to counteract the strength of being able to trade two cards instead of one. The extra trading allows the players to more precisely control who has access to which resources at a given time.

If the players had that amount of control *and* the extra 5 cards, the game would be too easy. The game is designed to be a challenge.

Comment: Did you manage to beat the game with 6 players? The thing is that having the ability to trade is great, but if you play with 6 players you will quickly end up in a situation where the 5th and 6th player basically can't trade anything since everyone has used all their cards.

Comment: Well, you kinda need to adjust your strategy to account for that. No matter how many people you are playing with, you can't really win the game without planning ahead.

Comment: Well, thanks for those words of wisdom :-D The problem is that if you don't use all 4 your cards each turn you are dead. If you use them, the other players won't be able to trade with you. After you do the first round you will have 6-8 cards on the table at most.

Comment: But you also go through the deck and get to new cards faster, get to reshuffle faster. There are a lot of things going into the balance there. Another option is to play the Overlord variation when you have 6 players.

Comment: You don't go through the deck faster. Not in relation to how fast you are drawing monsters. You actually go through the deck slower than in a 4 player game.

Comment: Touche about not going faster relative to drawing monsters.